# form using get instead of post

Tags: php, html, post, get

In my PHP I have...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
//do stuff
}
?>
```

Its not executing whats inside because the form isn't set. This is my HTML... (This is in a PHP echo so I have escape characters set)

```
<form class=\"form-vertical\" action=\"./index.php\" method=\"post\">
                <p>Enter username and password to continue.</p>
                <div class=\"control-group\">
                    <div class=\"controls\">
                        <div class=\"input-prepend\">
                            <span class=\"add-on\"><i class=\"icon-user\"></i></span><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" placeholder=\"Username\" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=\"control-group\">
                    <div class=\"controls\">
                        <div class=\"input-prepend\">
                            <span class=\"add-on\"><i class=\"icon-lock\"></i></span><input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" placeholder=\"Password\" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=\"form-actions\">
                    <span class=\"pull-left\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"flip-link\" id=\"to-recover\">Lost password?</a></span>
                    <span class=\"pull-left\" style=\"padding-left: 20px;\"><a href=\"\" class=\"flip-link\" id=\"to-register\">Register</a></span>
                    <span class=\"pull-right\"><input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-inverse\" value=\"Login\" /></span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

In my URL its using GET (index.php?username=blah&password=blah)

Comment: Your form is not creating a `GET` encoded URL, so where is the `GET` coming from?

Comment: Is there some additional javascript code we should know about?

Comment: There is some jQuery for changing a div z-index.

Comment: Just for debugging pourposes I took your code and pasted it in html and it worked fine.. possibly check on the Class in the form tag. And I know if a action is not set, then it defaults to get. I know you have one set, but just so you know this for debugging.

Comment: I solved the problem, I had another <form> ontop of it.

Comment: Makes sense lol. Like i said, if an action is not set, it will default to get.

Answer (score 0):

if you use $_REQUEST INinstead of $_GET or post it will pull it from the first one it finds in either post, get, cookie and session variables.

Comment: I'm passing password and sensitive information, I need to use post